# keras custom loss got wrong output when using Bayesian layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, bayesian-networks, tensorflow-probability

custom-loss-function of keras got wrong output: 
When I use a Bayesian layer (`tensorflow_probability.layers.DenseFlipout`), and use my custom loss function, I got a wrong output loss. But if I replace Bayesian layer by a traditional `tf.keras.layers.Dense` layer, the output is correct. Can anybody help me ?

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data as mnist_data

train, valid, test = mnist_data.read_data_sets('~/code/Python')

num_classes = 10
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
model = keras.Sequential()

#model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(10, activation = 'softmax', input_shape=(784,)))

sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=.1, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean((y_true-y_pred)**2)
model.compile(loss=my_loss, optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

x_train, y_train = train.images, train.labels
x_test, y_test = test.images, test.labels

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Please provide some more information: What output do you expect? What output do you actually get? Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: IF I choose Bayesian layer, the output of loss is:

Comment: IF I use Bayesian Dense layer, the output is:                                       128/55000 [..............................] - ETA: 8:00 - loss: 19844.8184 - ac 1280/55000 [..............................] - ETA: 49s - loss: 9604.8048                        but IF use traditional Dense layer, the correct output of loss function should be:   128/55000 [..............................] - ETA: 42s - loss: 0.0892 - acc: 0. 3456/55000 [>.............................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.0851 - acc: 0.2 7424/55000                   The Bayesian layer got a very large output.